# "name" web pdf for better default save filename in Acrobat?

Tags: http, pdf, content-type, acrobat

My app generates PDFs for user consumption.  The "Content-Disposition" http header is set as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74019/specifying-filename-for-dynamic-pdf-in-aspnet).  This is set to "inline; filename=foo.pdf", which should be enough for Acrobat to give "foo.pdf" as the filename when saving the pdf.

However, upon clicking the "Save" button in the browser-embedded Acrobat, the default name to save is not that filename but instead the URL with slashes changed to underscores.  Huge and ugly.  Is there a way to affect this default filename in Adobe?

There IS a query string in the URLs, and this is non-negotiable.  This may be significant, but adding a "&foo=/title.pdf" to the end of the URL doesn't affect the default filename.

Update 2: I've tried both

```
content-disposition  inline; filename=foo.pdf
Content-Type         application/pdf; filename=foo.pdf
```

and

```
content-disposition  inline; filename=foo.pdf
Content-Type         application/pdf; name=foo.pdf
```

(as verified through Firebug) Sadly, neither worked.

A sample url is

```
/bar/sessions/958d8a22-0/views/1493881172/export?format=application/pdf&no-attachment=true
```

which translates to a default Acrobat save as filename of

```
http___localhost_bar_sessions_958d8a22-0_views_1493881172_export_format=application_pdf&no-attachment=true.pdf
```

Update 3: Julian Reschke brings actual insight and rigor to this case.  Please upvote his answer.
This seems to be broken in FF (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433613) and IE but work in Opera, Safari, and Chrome. http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilenamepdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the relevant  [RFC 2183](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2183.html) doesn't really state what to do with a disposition type of "inline" and a filename.

Also, as far as I can tell, the only UA that actually uses the filename for type=inline is Firefox (see [test case](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilename)).

Finally, it's not obvious that the plugin API actually makes that information available (maybe someboy familiar with the API can elaborate).

That being said, I have sent a pointer to this question to an Adobe person; maybe the right people will have a look.

Related: see attempt to clarify Content-Disposition in HTTP in [draft-reschke-rfc2183-in-http](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-reschke-rfc2183-in-http-latest.html) -- this is early work in progress, feedback appreciated.

Update: I have added a [test case](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilenamepdf), which seems to indicate that the Acrobat reader plugin doesn't use the response headers (in Firefox), although the plugin API provides access to them.

Comment: I just tried to add
content-disposition  inline; filename=foo.pdf
and it seems to work in Chrome, at least.

Answer (score 11):

Set the **file name** in **ContentType** as well. This should solve the problem.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf; name=" + fileName;
// the usual stuff
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

After you set content-disposition header, also add content-length header, then use binarywrite to stream the PDF.

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
```

Comment: He's already done that. Acrobat Reader ignores it, or so it seems.

Comment: Suggestion is to set ContentType = "application/pdf; name=foo.pdf" which he doesn't say he tried it.

Comment: I had high hopes, but this doesn't seem to affect Acrobat Reader 8.0 in IE or FF.  Question updated.

Comment: Worked for me in FF 7.0 and Chrome 14. Failed in IE 9.

Answer (score 10):

Like you, I tried and tried to get this to work. Finally I gave up on this idea, and just opted for a workaround.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Framework, so I modified my routes for that controller/action to make sure that the served up PDF file is the last part of the location portion of the URI (before the query string), and pass everything else in the query string.

Eg:

Old URI:

http://server/app/report/showpdf?param1=foo&param2=bar&filename=myreport.pdf

New URI:

http://server/app/report/showpdf/myreport.pdf?param1=foo&param2=bar

The resulting header looks exactly like what you've described (content-type is application/pdf, disposition is inline, filename is uselessly part of the header). Acrobat shows it in the browser window (no save as dialog) and the filename that is auto-populated if a user clicks the Acrobat Save button is the report filename.

A few considerations:

In order for the filenames to look decent, they shouldn't have any escaped characters (ie, no spaces, etc)... which is a bit limiting. My filenames are auto-generated in this case, and before had spaces in them, which were showing up as '%20's in the resulting save dialog filename. I just replaced the spaces with underscores, and that worked out.

This is by no names the best solution, but it does work. It also means that you have to have the filename available to make it part of the original URI, which might mess with your program's workflow. If it's currently being generated or retrieved from a database during the server-side call that generates the PDF, you might need to move the code that generates the filename to javascript as part of a form submission or if it comes from a database make it a quick ajax call to get the filename when building the URL that results in the inlined PDF.

If you're taking the filename from a user input on a form, then that should be validated not to contain escaped characters, which will annoy users.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try placing the file name at the end of the URL, before any other parameters. This worked for me.
http://www.setasign.de/support/tips-and-tricks/filename-in-browser-plugin/

Comment: Awesome, I've been searching all over the internet for this feature and this is the place that I have found it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET 2.0 change the URL from

```
http://www. server.com/DocServe.aspx?DocId=XXXXXXX
```

to

```
http://www. server.com/DocServe.aspx/MySaveAsFileName?DocId=XXXXXXX
```

This works for Acrobat 8 and the default SaveAs filename is now `MySaveAsFileName.pdf`.

However, you have to restrict the allowed characters in `MySaveAsFileName` (no periods, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Apache's `mod_rewrite` can solve this.

I have a web service with an endpoint at `/foo/getDoc.service`. Of course Acrobat will save files as `getDoc.pdf`. I added the following lines in `apache.conf`:

```
LoadModule     RewriteModule         modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/foo/getDoc/(.*)$    /foo/getDoc.service     [P,NE]
```

Now when I request `/foo/getDoc/filename.pdf?bar&qux`, it gets internally rewritten to `/foo/getDoc.service?bar&qux`, so I'm hitting the correct endpoint of the web service, but Acrobat thinks it will save my file as `filename.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use asp.net, you can control pdf filename through page (url) file name.
As other users wrote, Acrobat is a bit s...  when it choose the pdf file name when you press "save" button: it takes the page name, removes the extension and add ".pdf". 
So /foo/bar/GetMyPdf.aspx  gives  GetMyPdf.pdf.

The only solution I found is to manage "dynamic" page names through an asp.net handler:

- create a class that implements IHttpHandler
- map an handler in web.config bounded to the class

Mapping1: all pages have a common radix (MyDocument_):

```
<httpHandlers>  
<add verb="*" path="MyDocument_*.ashx" type="ITextMiscWeb.MyDocumentHandler"/>
```

Mapping2: completely free file name (need a folder in path):

```
<add verb="*" path="/CustomName/*.ashx" type="ITextMiscWeb.MyDocumentHandler"/>
```

Some tips here (the pdf is dynamically created using iTextSharp):
http://fhtino.blogspot.com/2006/11/how-to-show-or-download-pdf-file-from.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attachment you can try inline:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=MyFile.pdf");
```

I used inline in a previous web application that generated Crystal Reports output into PDF and sent that in browser to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has already been mentioned in one flavor or another but I'll try and state it in my own words.

Rather than this:

```
/bar/sessions/958d8a22-0/views/1493881172/export?format=application/pdf&no-attachment=true
```

I use this:

```
/bar/sessions/958d8a22-0/views/1493881172/NameThatIWantPDFToBe.pdf?GeneratePDF=1
```

Rather than having "export" process the request, when a request comes in, I look in the URL for GeneratePDF=1.  If found, I run whatever code was running in "export" rather than allowing my system to attempt to search and serve a PDF in the location `/bar/sessions/958d8a22-0/views/1493881172/NameThatIWantPDFToBe.pdf`.  If GeneratePDF is not found in the URL, I simply transmit the file requested.  (note that I can't simply redirect to the file requested - or else I'd end up in an endless loop)

Answer (score 1):

File download dialog (PDF) with save and open option

Points To Remember:

1. Return Stream with correct array size from service
2. Read the byte arrary from stream with correct byte length on the basis of stream length.
3. set correct contenttype

Here is the code for read stream and open the File download dialog for PDF file

```
private void DownloadSharePointDocument()
{
    Uri uriAddress = new Uri("http://hyddlf5187:900/SharePointDownloadService/FulfillmentDownload.svc/GetDocumentByID/1/drmfree/");
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uriAddress) as HttpWebRequest;
    // Get response   
    using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        int byteCount = Convert.ToInt32(httpWebResponse.ContentLength);
        byte[] Buffer1 = new byte[byteCount];
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            Buffer1 = reader.ReadBytes(byteCount);
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        // set the content type to PDF 
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Filename.pdf");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer1);
        Response.Flush();
       // Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always have two links. One that opens the document inside the browser, and another to download it (using an incorrect content type). This is what Gmail does.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe this would be worse (with regards to user experience) than doing nothing.  Renaming a file is not a huge deal, just an annoying one.

Comment: Fair enough. Gmail does this with images, and I quite like it personally. Good luck anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was redirected here because i have the same problem. I also tried Troy Howard's workaround but it is doesn't seem to work.

The approach I did on this one is to NO LONGER use response object to write the file on the fly. Since the PDF is already existing on the server, what i did was to redirect my page pointing to that PDF file. Works great.

http://forums.asp.net/t/143631.aspx

I hope my vague explanation gave you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this (with PHP) is as follows:

Suppose your URL is `SomeScript.php?id=ID&data=DATA` and the file you want to use is `TEST.pdf`.

Change the URL to `SomeScript.php/id/ID/data/DATA/EXT/TEST.pdf`.

It's important that the last parameter is the file name you want Adobe to use (the 'EXT' can be about anything). Make sure there are no special chars in the above string, BTW.

Now, at the top of `SomeScript.php`, add:

```
$_REQUEST = MakeFriendlyURI( $_SERVER['PHP\_SELF'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

Then add this function to `SomeScript.php` (or your function library):

```
function MakeFriendlyURI($URI, $ScriptName) {

/* Need to remove everything up to the script name */
$MyName = '/^.*'.preg_quote(basename($ScriptName)."/", '/').'/';
$Str = preg_replace($MyName,'',$URI);
$RequestArray = array();

/* Breaks down like this
      0      1     2     3     4     5
    PARAM1/VAL1/PARAM2/VAL2/PARAM3/VAL3
*/

$tmp = explode('/',$Str);   
/* Ok so build an associative array with Key->value
   This way it can be returned back to $_REQUEST or $_GET
 */
for ($i=0;$i < count($tmp); $i = $i+2){
    $RequestArray[$tmp[$i]] = $tmp[$i+1];
}
return $RequestArray;       
}//EO MakeFriendlyURI
```

Now `$_REQUEST` (or `$_GET` if you prefer) is accessed like normal `$_REQUEST['id']`, `$_REQUEST['data']`, etc.

And Adobe will use your desired file name as the default save as or email info when you send it inline.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking at this, I used the solution found [here](http://docs.google.com/View?docid=dchmct9k_9dxkdwk) and it worked wonderfully.  Thanks Fabrizio!

Answer (score 0):

Credits to [Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7418/vivek).

---

## Nginx

```
location /file.pdf
{
    # more_set_headers "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=save_as_file.pdf";
    add_header Content-Disposition "inline; filename=save_as_file.pdf";
    alias /var/www/file.pdf;
}
```

Check with

```
curl -I https://example.com/file.pdf
```

Firefox 62.0b5 (64-bit): OK.

Chrome 67.0.3396.99 (64-Bit): OK.

IE 11: No comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, if your executable is "get.cgi"

http://server,org/get.cgi/filename.pdf?file=filename.pdf

Yes, it's completely insane. There is no file called "filename.pdf" on the server, there is directory at all under the executable get.cgi.

But it seems to work. The server ignores the filename.pdf and the pdf reader ignores the "get.cgi"

Dan

Comment: That seems to rely on a bug in your web server?  That should 404 according to spec - does Apache behave this way?

Comment: That's not *completely* insane, nor should it necessarily result in a 404. Additional paths following a CGI executable are valid, and should result in the CGI PATH_INFO variable being set.

That said, I don't think it's the cleanest way of solving this problem.