# IE9 / IE10 / IE11 downloads PDF instead of displaying with Content-Disposition = inline

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, pdf

We would like to display a PDF in the browser instead of downloading it. In IE11 with version `11.15.16299` and above this works as expected. In IE11 `11.0.9600` and below, the PDF is output as a download instead of displaying it. There are no errors within the console. Is there a solution for <=IE11?

*Note: we cannot save the file and pdf-base64 is not an option for the reasons described here [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843047/7302498)

Html

```
<!-- Tried workaround foo.pdf from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882132/7302498 -->
<form action="MyWebApiUrl/WriteFileStreamToResponse/foo.pdf" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="transferdata" id="transferdata"  />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Web-Api (C#)

```
private void WriteFileStreamToResponse(transferdata)
{
    var aFileStream= GetPdfAsFilestream(transferdata);
    byte[] pdfBytes = ReadFully(aFileStream);
    var response = HttpContext.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfBytes.Length.ToString());
    response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
    response.End();
}

private static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive

Comment: thanks but this is for downloading a PDF. But we want to display it in the IE <= Version 11

Comment: Content-Disposition header is documented on ietf.org: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266, and says: 

   On the other hand, if it matches "inline" (case-insensitively), this
   implies default processing.  Therefore, the disposition type "inline"
   is only useful when it is augmented with additional parameters, such
   as the filename (see below).

Comment: Thank you. I tried it now with `inline;filename=foo.pdf`, `attachment;filename=foo.pdf`, `attachment`. It is unfortunately still always output as download.

Comment: Is Adobe PDF Reader add-on enabled? https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html

Comment: Which makes it a client-dependent behaviour for good.